# Python converting nested JSON to CSV

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to convert a JSON file to CSV as structured below:

I'm using the json and csv modules and my current solution reads the json file, spits out the unique headers (a, b, c, d, ...)
Matches a slot to a header 
But does not write the csv yet.

My main issue is trying to convert something like:
inventory,a,b,...
slot1 a,b,...
to 0 and 1 values if the entity contains it

There's also a lot of for loops involved and I'm not sure that is best practice:
Nested for loop for getting all the headers,
Looping through the json file,
Writing csv file

tl;dr problem is:
translate list of "inventory items" from JSON per slot, to 0s and 1s in a CSV
I'd also like it to work for growing inventories (maybe e,f,g,h,...) more than 4 slots, etc 
So I'm trying to avoid any hard-coded rows and columns

First time using stackoverflow, thank you!

**equip_inventory.json**

```
{
    "slot1": ["a", "b"],
    "slot2": ["c", "d"],
    "slot3": ["a", "b", "c"]
    "slot4": ["d"]
}
```

**Intended output CSV**

```
inventory,a,b,c,d, ...
slot1,1,1,0,0,...
slot2,0,0,1,1,...
slot3,1,1,1,0,...
slot4,0,0,0,1,..
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable using a 3rd party library, can use [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) for this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"slot1": ["a", "b"],
     "slot2": ["c", "d"],
     "slot3": ["a", "b", "c"],
     "slot4": ["d"]}

df = pd.DataFrame([[d[i]] for i in d], index=d.keys())

dummies = pd.get_dummies(df[0].apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)

df = df.join(dummies)\
       .drop(0, axis=1)\
       .rename_axis('inventory')\
       .reset_index()

df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

  inventory  a  b  c  d
0     slot1  1  1  0  0
1     slot2  0  0  1  1
2     slot3  1  1  1  0
3     slot4  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do like this without pandas

```
import json
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile, open('sample.json') as jsonfile:
    data = json.load(jsonfile)
    for key, value in data.items():
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow([
            key,
            1 if 'a' in value else 0,
            1 if 'b' in value else 0,
            1 if 'c' in value else 0,
            1 if 'd' in value else 0]
            )
```

Comment: What happens if there are e, f, g,... etc, I would have to manually add each value correct?

Comment: use a for loop and append to list